# Physical switch for reconfiguring an Ethernet connection

Tags: switches, relay, ethernet, wire

I have an Ethernet connected device that I need to move from one switch to another from time to time.

I want to implement a way to do this remotely using an electronic or even physical switch.

Is it feasible to implement this by switching Tx and Rx through relays without completely losing throughput? I still need some 20 or 30 Mbps.

[image]

Comment: It will ruin the controlled impedance of the wire. However, it might still work if the wire is short and/or if you decrease the speed (100Mbps or 10Mbps mode, not just sending 10Mbps in 1000Mbps mode). There are "RF relays" which aim to work at higher frequencies than normal relays.

Comment: crazy idea: i wonder if it could be implemented by deliberately saturating ethernet magnetics by injecting DC...

Comment: Do you really need a physical switch though? Could you leave it plugged into the same switch, and then reconfigure the VLANs on the switch to send the packets to a different place? Because that is something that would Just Work, if it meets your needs.

Comment: This sounds like routing without extra steps.